# How to load a specific photo with dynamic URL with react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where a list of pictures is rendered and it works perfectly fine :

```
import { Component} from 'react'

import Header from '../Home/Header'
import Footer from '../Home/Footer'

import PhotoItems from './objet'

class Photos1930 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
 <h2 className='titre bloc'>Photos 1930</h2>
        <div className='bloc bloc__photo'>
          {PhotoItems.map((val, key) => {
            let id = val.id
            let url = val.url
            let lienImage = "/galerie/:" + (val.id)
            return <div key={id}>
              <a href={lienImage}>
              <img className='photo' alt='Photo Charles-Quint' src={url}></img>
              </a>
            </div>
          })}
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
  
    )
  }
  }
   

export default Photos1930
```

I want to create an other component where i can load a specific picture when user click on a picture from the precedent list. I use the same logic but for some reason the picture doesn't load. I don't have any errors in my console but on my page i just have the standard icon for image with my alt.
All the pictures are on public folder.
I just don't understand why is it working on one component but not on the other one.

```
import { Component } from 'react'

import Header from '../Home/Header'
import Footer from '../Home/Footer'

import PhotoItems from './objet'

const url = window.location.pathname
const justId = parseInt((url.split(':')[1]))

function specificId(photo) {
  return photo.id === (justId)
}

let justUrl = (PhotoItems.find(specificId).url)
console.log(justUrl)

class PickPhoto extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Header />
      <div>
      <h1>{justId}</h1>
        <img className="bigPhoto" alt="Charles-Quint" src={justUrl}></img>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>

    )
  }
}


export default PickPhoto
```

EDIT1 : Here's my github repo : https://github.com/FranMori/CharlesQuint
and here's my netlify link : https://stoic-bohr-810e13.netlify.app/
You can click on "Galerie Photos" and then click on any picture to see the problem.

Comment: How about putting `justUrl` inside the component?

Comment: I tried that it doesn't change anything

Comment: Have you tried to move all url, justId, specificId and justUrl inside the component?

Comment: try require(justUrl).default inside src

Comment: Yes @Peter, that was my first choice. But sadly it doesn't work either

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi i tried and now my page doesn't load at all and i have an error : Cannot find module with the url of the photo... The same url works fine in the other component. The two components are in the same folder and since the photos are on public folder the path should be the same for both... It's like one component can find the path and the other doesn't for some reason

Comment: can you make simple project on codesandbox ?

Comment: adding those variables inside componentDidMount() might work.

Comment: @Peter i just tried it doesn't work either

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi i edited my post with my github repo and my netlify link

Comment: @Dazak check out my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your repo, this.justUrl is undefined. You need to add `justUrl` in the component's state and update it dynamically inside `componentDidMount` like below. I also added a `/` in `src={`/${this.state.justUrl}`}`

```
import { Component } from 'react'

import Header from '../Home/Header'
import Footer from '../Home/Footer'

import PhotoItems from './objet'



class PickPhoto extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { justUrl: "" };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = window.location.pathname
    const justId = parseInt((url.split(':')[1]))

    function specificId(photo) {
      return photo.id === justId
    }
    let justUrl = (PhotoItems.find(specificId).url)
    console.log(justUrl)
    this.setState({justUrl})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Header />
      <div>
      <h1>{this.justId}</h1>
        <img className="bigPhoto" alt="Charles-Quint" src={`/${this.state.justUrl}`}></img>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>

    )
  }
}


export default PickPhoto
```